# How do I use an object as parameter for a function in C++?

Tags: c++, class, stack, tuples, runtime-error

I wanted to implement a stack and then use it to solve a problem. I defined a
class named Stack this way:

```
template<typename T>
class Stack
{ ... }
```

Inside this class I have the basic stack functions. Inside main I created a Stack object:

```
Stack<tuple<string, int, int, int, int> > S;
```

Inside main, the following code works (it prints cabs):

```
S.Push_back(make_tuple("cabs", 1, 2, 3, 4));
cout<<get<0>(S.Top())<<" ";
read_command(S);
```

As you can see, inside main I called another function named read_command and I want to use the stack I created as a parameter. This is the part of it that uses my stack:

```
void read_command(Stack<tuple<string, int, int, int, int> > S)
{  
    ... 
    S.Push_back(make_tuple("abc", 1, 2, 3, 4));
    cout<<get<0>(S.Top());
    S.Pop_back();
}
```

Lastly, this is how I declared my function above main:

```
void read_command(Stack<tuple<string, int, int, int, int> >);
```

When I run this program it returns the following error:

```
std::_Head_base<0u, std::string, false>::~_Head_base (this=0x3834f008, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) 
at C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/tuple:128
```

How can I add values to the stack I declared in main inside other functions? I think I did not use the right parameters, but it's the first time I work with tuple and classes.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Is that a *build* error? Then it's not the full error message. Please copy-paste the full and complete output.

Comment: `read_command` takes a copy of your stack as a parameter. If you want to make changes to the original stack you'll need to pass it by reference.

Comment: No, it's not a build error (I think). I'm using codeblocks and this is what I get in the call stack after I use the debugger. I also get a notice that my program has a segmentation fault.

Comment: If you need a stack there's no *need* to build one yourself. [std::stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem appropriate to pass the stack to an external subroutine *by value*, i.e. as a *copy*. IMHO you should pass it as a reference instead:

```
void read_command(Stack<tuple<string, int, int, int, int> >&S) { ... }
```

Note an ampersand preceding the `S`.

Possibly the reference should be non-modifiable, it the function is not allowed to modify the stack:

```
void read_command(Stack<tuple<string, int, int, int, int> > const &S) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. If inside read_command I want to call another function and edit my Stack (S) what should I do? Should I call it using different_function(S)? And then add an ampersand to the definition of different_function?

Comment: @M.Ritz Generally, all actions specific and immanent to the stack (say, adding an item on top of the stack, reading the top item, removing the top item, testing whether the stack is empty, etc.) should be defined as the stack's methods. Then – yes, you pass around a reference to the stack, so all routines use the same stack variable (and not its temporary copies), but the stack class itself is responsible for managing the internal data structure.